Prove that there are no more numbers that belong to the spectrum or find them

Find the spectrum of the operator $ A $ in $L^2[0, \pi]$ if
$$(Ax)(t) = \int\limits_0^\pi \cos(t+2s)x(s) \, ds$$

Consider the operator $A$ in the space $L^2[0,\pi]$ given by the rule $(Ax)(t)=\int\limits_0^\pi \cos(t+2s)x(s)\,ds$. Let us decompose the kernel of the integral operator using the identity for the cosine: $\cos(t+2s)=\cos t \cos(2s)-\sin t \sin(2s)$. Then
$$(Ax)(t)=\cos t \int\limits_0^\pi x(s)\cos(2s)\,ds \;-\; \sin t \int\limits_0^\pi x(s)\sin(2s)\,ds$$
Let's denote
$$a=\int\limits_0^\pi x(s)\cos(2s)\,ds, \quad b=-\int\limits_0^\pi x(s)\sin(2s)\,ds\Rightarrow (Ax)(t)=a\cos t + b\sin t$$
This shows that the image of the operator $A$ lies in the two-dimensional subspace generated by the functions $\cos t$ and $\sin t$. Hence, $A$ is an operator of finite rank (at most 2). For operators of finite rank in an infinite-dimensional space, zero always belongs to the spectrum, since such an operator cannot be surjective and its reversible operator (if it existed) would not be bounded over the entire infinite-dimensional region. To find the remaining eigenvalues, consider the operator $A$ on the two-dimensional subspace generated by $\cos t$ and $\sin t$. To do this, let us compute the matrix of the operator in this basis. Take $x(s)=\cos s$ and find $A(\cos t)$
$$a=\int\limits_0^\pi \cos s \cos(2s) \, ds, \quad b=-\int\limits_0^\pi \cos s \sin(2s)\, ds$$
Integrating, we obtain $a=0$, and for $b$ the integral gives $b=-\frac{4}{3}$. Hence,
$$A(\cos t)=0\cdot \cos t + \left(-\frac{4}{3}\right)\sin t$$
Similarly, for $x(s)=\sin s$ we calculate
$$a=\int\limits_0^\pi \sin s \cos(2s) \, ds, \quad b=-\int\limits_0^\pi \sin s \sin(2s)\, ds$$
The integrals give $a=-2/3$ and $b=0$, whence $A(\sin t)=-\frac{2}{3}\cos t + 0\cdot \sin t$. Thus, in the basis $(\cos t,\sin t)$ the operator $A$ is represented by the matrix
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -2/3\\[6pt]
-4/3 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
The eigenvalues of this matrix are found from Eq
$$\det\begin{pmatrix}\lambda & \frac{2}{3}\\ \frac{4}{3} & \lambda\end{pmatrix}=\lambda^2-\frac{8}{9}=0\Rightarrow \lambda=\pm \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}$$
The problem is that I can't find other values that belong to the spectrum or prove that there are no more such values. I could find only three values, but I don't know how to finish the problem yet. Can you help me to prove that there are no more such values or to find them ?

There are no more eigenvalues. Every function orthogonal to $\cos(2s)$ and $\sin(2s)$ belongs to $\ker T.$

The short answer is that you're basically at the finish line.
You (should) know that the non-zero elements of the spectrum of a compact operator, which a finite rank operator is, are exactly the non-zero eigenvalues, so that you only have to look out for eigenvalues.
Using this information, for a very slightly more general setting, let's say you have a compact operator $A$ and you find all the eigenvalues of $A|_{\operatorname{ran} A} =: M$, just like what you've done here. This is of course easier when $A$ has finite rank, but it can be done for some other operators.
Well, the image by $A$ of any vector belongs to the range of $A$ by definition, so that the eigenvalues of $A$ have to also belong to the range of $A$, meaning that in actuality you had already done most of the work. That is, not forgetting the special case of $0$, you've successfully computed the spectrum of $A$.

The operator is of the form $$Ax=\langle x,u_1\rangle v_1+\langle x,u_2\rangle v_2$$ where $u_1,u_2$ are linearly independent and $v_1,v_2$ are linearly independent. If $x\perp u_1,u_2$ then $Ax=0.$ Any eigenvector must belong to the range of $A,$ i.e. is a linear combination of $v_1,v_2.$ Therefore, besides the $0$ eigenvalue, we should determine the eigenvalues of the operator $A$ restricted to the subspace generated by $v_1,v_2.$ The corresponding $2\times 2$ matrix is $$\begin{pmatrix}\langle v_1,u_1\rangle &\langle v_2,u_1\rangle\\ \langle v_1,u_2\rangle &\langle v_2,u_2\rangle\end{pmatrix}$$ Thus it suffices to determine the eigenvalues of that matrix.
